# Win 7 stuck in restore point at boot up

Tags: windows-7, restore

I had my motherboard or cpu go bad, replaced them the other night.

After fooling for hours trying to get the bios correct, win7 kept asking to do a restore.
I eventually gave in, and it did not work.
The computer is now functioning, it was 1 setting in the bios that was causing all the issues, never needed a restore.

Now, when the system restarts (and sometimes on a fresh power up) win7 tries to still do the restore, and gets locked up, or I get a screen that says to delete the restore info an start win normally.
I keep doing this, and its not getting rid of this restore point.

Any ideas what to fix?

Win7 reinstall is my last option, if i really start getting annoyed by the rebooting problem. 
It seems after i do the delete the system starts fine, then when it runs an update patch, it wants to do the restore on next restart.